# Set universal route

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm trying create some simple SPA. How can I set a universal route for root page?
For example, in Laravel possible make this.

```
Route::any('{any?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any','.*');
```

But i'dont figure out how this make in Zend Framework 3

Comment: What do you mean by "generic route"? Can you explain a bit what you are trying to achieve? It will help us to understand better your problem and give you a solution :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know English well. But I already knew what to do
https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Regex_Route_Type.html

Comment: So, what you want to achieve is to have a list of defined routes for your API, and then a single route that matches everything else, in order to avoid the 404 page, is that right?

Comment: @Ermenegildo Yes, i already shared solution

Comment: Just wanted to make sure to understand the situation, check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

I have a basic "App" module. Then I created a new module " Api " And here is what I have in the module configurations

```
//module App, file: config.module.php
'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Regex::class,
                'options' => [
                    'regex'    => '([^\?]+)(\?.*)?',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                    'spec' => ''
                ],
            ],
        ],


//module Api file:config.module.php
'routes' => [
            'api_index' => [
                'type'    => Regex::class,
                'options' => [
                    'regex'    => '/api/v1/(?<index>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\V1\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                    'spec' => '/api/v1/%index%'
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of routes, you must pay a lot of attention of their order.

According to [Zend router documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/#routing):

```
Routes will be queried in a LIFO order, and hence the reason behind the name RouteStack.
```

[Moreover:](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/#simpleroutestack)

```
As such, routes that will match most often should be registered last,
and least common routes first.
[...]
Alternatively, you can set priorities by giving the priority as third parameter
to the addRoute() method, specifying the priority in the route specifications 
or setting the priority property within a route instance before adding it 
to the route stack.
```

In your case, the fact that given config is working is just a "lucky coincidence" (well, module order declaration helps a bit), because you are using a route to match **everything**, even what should be matched by the api route.

What I suggest you is to add the priority to those routes, in order to be sure that the "match everything" route will be the last to be tested:

```php
//module App, file: config.module.php
'routes' => [
    'home' => [
        'type' => Regex::class,
        'priority' => -1000, // make sure that this will be tested as last
        'options' => [
            'regex' => '([^\?]+)(\?.*)?',
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                'action' => 'index',
            ],
            'spec' => ''
        ],
    ],
],
```

The `Api module` route is perfect